# Problem with android regex to extract data - PID on log

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm noob on Android and I'm trying to extract the PID of a Android log but when I tried with regex don't extract the value to my variable. The format of the log message is this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14700): Process: com.example.log_v_02, PID: 14700
```

But sometime the format is this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4700): Process: com.example.log_v_02, PID: 14700
```

With a space after the first "("

I'm using pattern and matcher class to make it, this is my code:

```
Pattern saca_pid = Pattern.compile(".*( [0-9]{1,4}).*||.*([0-9]{5,}).*");
StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
String line = "";
while (true) {
    try {
        if (!((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)) break;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Boolean matches = Pattern.matches(patron_malicioso,line);

    Matcher encuentra_pid = saca_pid.matcher(line);
    if(encuentra_pid.find())
    {
        String pid = encuentra_pid.group(1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex alternation is a *single* pipe, i.e. `|`, *not* a double pipe `||`, which is logical OR.  An exact fix to your code would be:

```
Pattern saca_pid = Pattern.compile(".*( [0-9]{1,4}).*|.*([0-9]{5,}).*");
```

Fixing this problem might make your code work, but I would suggest using the following pattern:

```
\(\s*(\d+)\):
```

Your updated code:

```
Pattern saca_pid = Pattern.compile("\\(\\s*(\\d+)\\):");
StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
String line = "";
while (true) {
    try {
        if (!((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)) break;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Matcher encuentra_pid = saca_pid.matcher(line);
    if (encuentra_pid.find()) {
        String pid = encuentra_pid.group(1);
    }
}
```

The updated pattern completely avoids the need for an alternation by making the leading space in front of the number optional.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but still doesn't work correctly, can't extract the data and can't detect the (NUMBER) for example on this:
E/AndroidRuntime(14700): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Can't extract and detect the 14700

Comment: The regex pattern I gave you is correct, [see here](https://regex101.com/r/AMIJT5/1).  There must be some other problem with your code.